# NLua - does the application shown on the webpage exist somewhere?

Tags: c#, lua, nlua

On the [NLua web page](http://nlua.org/) there is an image of a live Lua interpreter (edit: for Windows) that uses the NLua bindings.  Does this exist for download somewhere?

I know Lua very well but I have a very limited understanding of C# and would strongly prefer not to have to build from source if possible.

Thanks a bunch in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did build the NLua from the source on my machine, here is the link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz0PoV2jLHizZHJ4blJ2TlNuWTQ/view?usp=sharing you will need the vcredist for the Visual Studio 2015

Thank you